# Django Getting this error with UpdateView: NoReverseMatch at /user/2/edit

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have an update view for users to update their profiles. However I keep getting this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /user/2/edit
Reverse for 'user_profile' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']
```

Nothing I've tried is working (adding a pk, etc.).

**The UpdateView:**

```
class UserEditProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    model = UserProfile
    fields = [
            'first_name',
            'profile_pic',
            'location',
            'title',
            'user_type',
            'website',
            'about',
            'twitter',
            'dribbble',
            'github'
            ]
    template_name_suffix = '_edit_form'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:user_profile')
```

**App urls:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from users import views

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.UserListView.as_view(),name='user_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.detailprofile,name='user_profile'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit$',views.UserEditProfileView.as_view(),name='user_profile_edit'),
    url(r'^login/$',views.user_login,name='user_login'),
    url(r'^logout/$',views.user_logout,name='user_logout'),
    url(r'^register/$',views.register,name='register'),
]
```

**Edit profile template:**

```
{% extends "users/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="form-base">
        <h2>Edit Profile</h2>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Let me know if you need to see anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to provide `pk` in `user_profile`

```
class UserEditProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    model = UserProfile
    fields = [
        'first_name',
        'profile_pic',
        'location',
        'title',
        'user_type',
        'website',
        'about',
        'twitter',
        'dribbble',
        'github'
        ]
    template_name_suffix = '_edit_form'

    def get_success_url(self):
        userid = self.kwargs['pk']
        return reverse_lazy('users:user_profile', kwargs={'pk': userid})
```

Comment: That's what I tried but it gives me a name error: `NameError: name 'pk' is not defined`

Comment: That worked, so I just needed to use a `get_success_url` method to establish the pk and return it. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, You just need to pass `pk` and for collecting `pk` that function.

Comment: Please upvote and select my answer if it solved your purpose. Thanks for cooperation.